# Angular trigger EventEmitter whenever object contents is changed

Tags: javascript, angular, output, components, eventemitter

I'm using a child component to build a complex object consisting of recursive child arrays and objects. I'd like a way to get access to this object in the parent component using live binding.

Values within the object change based on user input (select boxes, inputs etc.), so I need a way to emit the @Output() EventEmitter and pass the entire object whenever one if it's properties change.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this or is there another route I can take?

See some concept code below, in which the input has two-way data binding to a deep value in the complex object, and I need to emit this change to a parent by detecting the change somehow.

The actual form is more complex, so I'd like to avoid using specific events like watching for a change in each of the inputs to manually trigger the event emitter if possible.

Parent template:

```
<child-component (emitter)="emitterHandler($event)"></child-component>
```

Parent component:

```
emitterHandler(obj){ console.log(obj); }
```

Child component:

```
@Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();    
complexObj = {data: 'test', lines: [{data: 'asd', time: 123},{data: 'xcv', time: 233}]};
```

Child template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="complexObj.lines[0].data"></input>
```

Comment: you can emit eventemitter on change of your input `<input [(ngModel)]="complexObj.lines[0].data" (change)="emitEmitter()"></input>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The form is a little more complex than illustrated with lots of potential inputs. It would be a shame to have to use on change detection for each of the inputs. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `valueChanges` of the `NgForm` :

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;

// this will be called when any input inside the form changes
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    // emit the event
});
```

**Template**

```
<form #myForm='ngForm' ...>
    // your select , input or nany form elements
</form>
```

Above code is for template driven form,

Here is the article for data-driven form  on this :
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/

---

Nice way to go is :

```
this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(res => {
    if (res === 'VALID') {
       // emit(this.myForm.values)
    }
});
```

This will emit the values when the data is valid, and in above code, no matter values is right or wrong it will fire the event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to try it out. The child component actually consists of a bunch of recursion, with children creating children of the same type etc. Is there anyway good way to conditionally wrap the top level component in the <form></form> tags so I can access all the possible child inputs?

Comment: e.g. Child template might have: <input /><child-component /><input /> (and recursively create more inputs this way), if I wrap the entire thing in a form tags, I will have nested forms

Comment: this wont work on nested component ? as ngForm is also not able to get values from nested inputs.